# ExtJs. Fields layout on resize

Tags: extjs

I have a window with nested panel. Panel contains several fields.
Fields of the panel layouts incorrectly after window resize event.

```
    var panel = new Ext.panel.Panel({
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            align: 'stretch'
        },
        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'One Two Three Four Five Six Seven',
            labelAlign: 'top',
            width: '100%'
        },{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'One Two Three Four Five Six Seven',
            labelAlign: 'top',
            width: '100%'
        }]
    })

    var window = new Ext.Window({
        layout: 'anchor',
        title: 'Hello resizer',
        resizable: true,
        draggable: true,
        scrollable: 'vertical',
        items: [panel],
        width: 400,
        height: 200,
    });
```

Way to reproduce:

1. Go to this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/21c1)

2. Resize the window so that label of the textfield doesn't fit into one line. (here you'll see the positioning problems)

[image]

Is there a way to correctly show the fields avoiding updateLayout, changing the layout types?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in ExtJs. One workaround is to pass a custom configuration to the [`Ext.resizer.Resizer`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.resizer.Resizer.html). Specify `dynamic` as true to update the component dynamically during dragging.

```
var window = new Ext.Window({
    //[...]
    resizable: {
        dynamic: true
    },
    //[...]
});
```

Here is the full example:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/21c3